# Oauth2 token that restricts access to a single resource

Tags: security, authentication, claims-based-identity, identityserver3, oauth-2.0

We make use of a thrird party Email Service Provider (ESP) to send emails to our customers. One of the emails needs to have a file attached to it. To accomplish this we need to give the ESP a URL of the file. The ESP will download the file and attach it to the email.

We are now working on a solution to secure the URL to limit the risk of unauthorized downloads. The ESP cannot authenticate itself while making the request to the URL, so the only option we see is by making the URL hard to guess and making it valid for a limited time.

The way we want to accomplish this is by putting a token in the URL's querystring. The service that hosts the file will validate the token and authorize access. The token will need to expire in time and should only give access to a specific file.

We already have a IdentityServer 3 implementation running an oAuth2 Security Token Service. Our plan is to let this service generate the tokens that will be put in the query string of the file download URL. We are considering creating a custom oAuth2 grant type to support tokens that will only allow access to a specific resource.

This would be an example of a request to the oauth2 token endpoint with the custom grant:

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=custom_grant&scope=attachment.read&resource_id=xxxxx
```

The STS will return a token with a claim of the resource ID the token will give access to.

Is the right use case for a custom grant type or should we look for a different way to implement this?

Comment: Can't Client credentials grant be used for this (with scope as you described), but the claim is passed to the ESP for sending within the URL? i.e. Your client asks the STS for the token (you can authenticate against the STS using your private credentials to get an access token), which you can then pass as the attachment path.

Comment: We thought about that but the problem is that this access token will give access to all resources for that scope, instead of a specific one. The resource identifier needs to be added to the token, something that is not possible in the client credentials grant.

Comment: Can't the scope be narrowed for a single attachment? e.g. `attachment.read.attachmentid.142184712984721`

Comment: I don't think that is the intended usage of oAuth2 scopes.

Comment: Scope can be anything you want it to be. Have a look here to how Facebook uses it: https://brandur.org/oauth-scope#facebook

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but I don't think this is the best solution in our situation. Our current infrastructure doesn't support these kind of dynamic scopes. Each client is configured with a fixed set of scopes. Also some custom parsing would be needed in the authorization logic to extract the resource identifier. When the identifier would be added to the token as a separate claim we can rely on existing libraries (as @smarx suggests) to parse the token values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're proposing is fine, but I personally prefer using something based on cryptographic signatures for this sort of thing.

[JSON Web Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) is a well-established way to do this with support in a lot of programming languages. Essentially, you sign a JSON dictionary, including an expiration time. Then you attach it to the URL (e.g. as a query parameter). When receiving an inbound request, you validate the token by checking the signature, expiration time, and the resource it says it applies to.

The advantage of this approach is that there's no needless state: you don't have to store tokens anywhere and instead just need a signing key.

Here's an example in Python that shows the basic idea:

```
import time

import jwt

SIGNING_SECRET = 'use-a-good-secret-here'

token = jwt.encode({
    'resource_id': 'xxxxx',
    # JSON spec establishes "exp" as meaning expiration time
    'exp': time.time() + 1, # one second in the future for testing
}, SIGNING_SECRET, algorithm='HS256')

print(token)

def try_decoding(token):
    try:
        decoded = jwt.decode(token, SIGNING_SECRET, algorithms=['HS256'])
        print('Valid token for "{}"'.format(decoded['resource_id']))
    except jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError:
        print('The token has expired.')

try_decoding(token) # prints 'Valid token for "xxxxx"'
print('Sleeping until the token expires...')
time.sleep(2)
try_decoding(token) # prints "The token has expired."
```

Comment: how can you verify the signature, I got an access token but i cant decode it.